# getting email ids using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on python. I am learning beautifulsoup & I am parsing a link.

my url :

```
http://www.dtemaharashtra.gov.in/approvedinstitues/StaticPages/frmInstituteSummary.aspx?InstituteCode=1002
```

I want to parse email id from that url.
How can I do that?

Comment: What e-mail id? principal@gcoea.ac.in ?

Comment: yes i want to get that email id

Comment: lol. no. I am learning the beautifulsoup and html so for easy exmple I choose this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.dtemaharashtra.gov.in/approvedinstitues/StaticPages/frmInstituteSummary.aspx?InstituteCode=1002').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find(id='ctl00_rightContainer_ContentBox1_lblEMailAddress').text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://www.dtemaharashtra.gov.in/approvedinstitues/StaticPages/frmInstituteSummary.aspx?InstituteCode=1002")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
soup.find("span", {"id":"ctl00_rightContainer_ContentBox1_lblEMailAddress"}).text
```